# Integration by parts vs integration by parts with substitution different answers

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, change-of-variable

I'm trying to integrate

$$\int(5x^4+1)\ln(x^5+x)dx$$

When I use an online calculator (it first uses substitution and then integration by parts) I get the answer

$$(x^5+x)\ln(x^5+x)-x^5-x$$

but when I try a different approach (without substitution only with integration by parts) I get

$$(x^5+x)\ln(x^5+x)-x$$

(I change the variable of $dx$ to $x^5+x$)

Comment: The first is correct modulo a constant of integration, the second is wrong. Without any more info, this is because you didn't do the second method correctly.

Comment: Use Latex to type your question. Put all the math parts inside two dollar signs $$ and use the command \int_{}^{} to display your intergral

Comment: Is that integral supposed to be $\int(5x^4+1)\ln(x^5+x)dx$ ?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem's that you forgot something since diferentiation of $(x^5+x)\ln(x^5+x)-x$ gives:
\begin{align*}
D_x\left[(x^5+x)\ln(x^5+x)-x\right]&=(5x^4+1)\ln(x^5+x)+5x^4+1-1\\
&=(5x^4+1)\ln(x^5+x)+5x^4
\end{align*}
And in the expression
$$(x^5+x)\ln(x^5+x)-x$$
the last $x$ must be $x^5+x$ because the change that you used in order to integrate, i.e. $x^5+x$ instead of $x$.

Comment: oh it seems I didn't calculate the first derivate the right way... didn't see it was a function of a function...

Answer (score 0):

Since your  integral looks like $\int g’\ln(g)$ you just need to find a primitive of $\ln( x)$, namely $x\cdot\ln(x)-x$, and just plug in $x^5+x$ for $g$.

Answer (score 0):

**Integration with x only**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\left(5 x^4+1\right) \ln \left(x^5+x\right) d x&=\int \ln \left(x^5+x\right) d\left(x^5+x\right) \\
&=\left(x^5+x\right) \ln \left(x^5+x\right)-\int\left(x^5+x\right) \frac{5 x^4+1}{x^5+x} d x \\
&=\left(x^5+x\right) \ln \left(x^5+x\right)-\int\left(5 x^4+1\right) d x \\
&=\left(x^5+x\right) \ln \left(x^5+x\right)-x^5-x+C
\end{aligned}
$$
**Integration with a new variable u**

Let $u=x^5+x$, then $d u=\left(5 x^4+1\right) d x$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\left(5 x^4+1\right) \ln \left(x^5+x\right) d x &=\int \ln u d u \\
&=u \ln u-\int u \cdot \frac{1}{u} d u \\
&=u \ln u-u+C \\
&=\left(x^5+x\right) \ln \left(x^5+x\right)-x^5-x+C
\end{aligned}
$$